# C# : Modify a xml node

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

i have that xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<reminders>
  <reminder>
    <Title>Alarm1</Title>
    <Description>Desc1</Description>
    <Time>03/07/2012 10:11AM</Time>
    <snooze>1</snooze>
    <repeat>None</repeat>
  </reminder>
</reminders>
```

And i want to modify the  innertext from Alarm1 to another value so i wrote that code which actually duplicate the entire node .

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        xml.Load("0.xml");

        XmlNodeList elements = xml.SelectNodes("//reminders");

        foreach (XmlNode element in elements)
        {
            if (element.InnerText == "Alarm1")
            {
                XmlNode newvalue = xml.CreateElement("MODIFIED");
                element.ReplaceChild(newvalue, element);

                xml.Save("0.xml");
            }
        }
```

And then tried another code :

```
        foreach (XmlElement element in xml.SelectNodes("//reminder"))
        {
            if (element.InnerText == "Alarm1")
            {
                XmlNode newvalue = xml.CreateElement("MODIFIED");
                element.ReplaceChild(newvalue, element);

                xml.Save("0.xml");
            }
        }
```

But also doesn`t work....

EDIT 1 : [Figured out a new code]

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        xml.Load("0.xml");

        foreach (XmlElement element in xml.SelectNodes("//reminder"))
        {
            foreach (XmlElement element1 in element)
            {
                if (element.SelectSingleNode("//Title").InnerText == "Alarm1")
                {
                    XmlNode newvalue = xml.CreateElement("MODIFIED");
                    element.ReplaceChild(newvalue, element1);

                    xml.Save("0.xml");
                }
            }
        }
```

But it made the Alarm1 becomes

```
<MODIFIED />
```

EDIT 2 : [I SOLVED IT :D]
Okay here is the code i could figure out :

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        xml.Load("0.xml");

        foreach (XmlElement element in xml.SelectNodes("//reminder"))
        {
            foreach (XmlElement element1 in element)
            {
                if (element.SelectSingleNode("//Title").InnerText == "Alarm1")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(element1.InnerText);
                    XmlNode newvalue = xml.CreateElement("Title");
                    newvalue.InnerText = "MODIFIED";
                    element.ReplaceChild(newvalue, element1);

                    xml.Save("0.xml");
                }
            }
        }
```

I`ll really appreciate your helps and thanks.

Comment: use `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`

Comment: your examples and selected answer have nothing to do with linq

Comment: If you are going with EDIT2: but a `break;` in the `if` to prevent unesscessary looping

Comment: hi , if i hava three reminder node , How I can Update the second node ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
xml.SelectSingleNode("//reminder/Title").InnerText = "NewValue";
```

Your `foreach` line is simply looping through a list of elements called "reminders", not it's child nodes.

Take a look at this xpath tutorial for more information:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: Was just the first resource I came by and has always been a useful source for me in the past, whether respected or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use linq with xml (I find it the best way) then you will want to use the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace. The classes in that namespace are all prefixed with just `X` not `Xml`. The functionality in this namespace is newer, better and much easier to manipulate with Linq.

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("0.xml");
var alarm1 = xml.Descendants("reminder")
                .Single(r => r.Element("Title") == "Alarm1");
```

This code will give you a variable, `alarm1` that is the reminder that has a title node of "Alarm1."

From that point its not clear to me exactly what you want to modify. If you just want to change the title then ...

```
alarm1.Element("Title").Value = "MODIFIED";
xml.Save("0.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("0.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> rech =
                     from el in doc.Root.Elements("reminder")
                     where (string)el.Element("Title") == "Alarm1"
                     select el;
if (rech.Count() != 0)
{
   foreach (XElement el in rech)
   {
       el.Element("Title").SetValue("NEW TITLE");
   }
}
doc.Save("0.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(.....);
xDoc.Descendants("Title").First().Value = "New Value";
xDoc.Save(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(...);

var newTitle = "MODIFIED";
var title_node = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Title");
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newTitle) && title_node.Count > 0)
{
    title_node[0].InnerText = newTitle;
}
```